# Pass a value from broadcastreceiver class to main activity in wifi direct

Tags: java, android, eclipse, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I want to send the value in string variable **result**, which is in the **WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver**, to **WiFiDirectActivity** and I tried doing it as shown in [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340934/pass-data-from-broadcastreceiver-class-to-a-android-activity?rq=1)

but when I ran the application it kept searching for peers. when I comment those added lines (last 3 line of WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver) it works fine.

codes for **onReceive** function in WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver and upto **onResume()** in WiFiDirectActivity are added.

how I can pass that value to WiFiDirectActivity? what am I missing here?

**WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

      //if (MyIntentService.ACTION_MyIntentService.equals(action))
     // {
        //result = intent.getStringExtra(MyIntentService.EXTRA_KEY_OUT);
          result = "hello";
      //}

    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        // UI update to indicate wifi p2p status.
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
        if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
            // Wifi Direct mode is enabled
            activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
        } else {
            activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);
            activity.resetData();

        }
        Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "P2P state changed - " + state);
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        // request available peers from the wifi p2p manager. This is an
        // asynchronous call and the calling activity is notified with a
        // callback on PeerListListener.onPeersAvailable()
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.requestPeers(channel, (PeerListListener) activity.getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list));
        }
        Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "P2P peers changed");
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        if (manager == null) {
            return;
        }

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {

            // we are connected with the other device, request connection
            // info to find group owner IP

            DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) activity
                    .getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
            manager.requestConnectionInfo(channel, fragment);
            //fragment.peerCountInfo=result;
            //fragment.peerCt = peerCountFromDlist;
            //fragment.peerNm = peerNameFromDlist;
        } else {
            // It's a disconnect
            activity.resetData();
        }
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) activity.getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
        fragment.updateThisDevice((WifiP2pDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(
                WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE));
        //peerCountFromDlist = fragment.peerTot;
        //peerNameFromDlist = fragment.deviceid;

    }

    intent.putExtra("message",result);
    intent.setClass(context, WiFiDirectActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

**WiFiDirectActivity.java**

```
public class WiFiDirectActivity extends Activity implements ChannelListener, DeviceActionListener {
```

`public static final String TAG = "wifidirectdemo";
private WifiP2pManager manager;
private boolean isWifiP2pEnabled = false;
private boolean retryChannel = false;

private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
private Channel channel;
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;
private String resultString; 
private int peerCount;

/**
 * @param isWifiP2pEnabled the isWifiP2pEnabled to set
 */
public void setIsWifiP2pEnabled(boolean isWifiP2pEnabled) {
    this.isWifiP2pEnabled = isWifiP2pEnabled;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // add necessary intent values to be matched.

    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(MyIntentService.ACTION_MyIntentService);

    manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
}

/** register the BroadcastReceiver with the intent values to be matched */
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    receiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel, this);
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        resultString = extras.getString("message");
    }
}`

Comment: have u tried SharedPreferences?

Comment: hey guys, thanks for your answers! I actually tried the things i'm familiar with since i'm a bit new to android! 
@Itzik what is SharedPreferences?

Comment: @Mike i can understand the retrieval part now, sorry, but what do you mean by put info into the "Intent you're using to start the Activity"?

Comment: oh i think i get the point, but it would be nice if you can post the answer i really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Mike oh thank you, i get it now! it was right there in that demo coding (setIsWifiP2pEnabled is done the same way) and i didn't see it. i feel stupid for asking the question now lol sorry for your time and thank you very much for pointing that!
add it as an answer if you want, then i'll mark it as the answer :)

Comment: @Mike ohh that's fine, you answered somehow and thank you for that! I have added the answer. thanks again.

Comment: yeah yeah! it was the "wifi-direct demo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this easy way to send some data to Main Activity from BroadcastReceiver thanks to Mike M. (same way **setIsWifiP2pEnabled(boolean isWifiP2pEnabled)** method works)

sending `"message"` and retrieving it to `str` variable ;

**create a public method in the MainActivity :**

```
   public void setResult(String result){
          str = result;
}
```

**Then call it in the BroadcastReceiver :**

`activity.setResult("message");`