# Set text on textView in background process

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

So, I have my application which has BroadcastReceiver and receives notification from other application. The problem is, I am receiving a message, displaying it in the phone via Toast, but I want to set it visible on my TextView. I have only two classes in my whole app.

My receiver is my own class which extends BroadcastReceiver and its onReceive method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String value =  intent.getExtras().getString("hiddenMessage");
    MainActivity.getInstace().updateTheTextView(value);
}
```

Here's the code of the method which updates textView. This method is in MainActivity class:

```
public void updateTheTextView(final String textFromNotification) {
    final Context context = this;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Message received: " + textFromNotification, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();

    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textV1.setText(textFromNotification);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, when I send a notification from one app and receive it here, text is not visible. It's only visible when this app is open. How can I set text to field when my app is not open? Store message to some class field and use setText() in onResume method?

Comment: Where is the above code located? Is the broadcast receiver instance created and registered/unregistered in the same class?

Comment: store it in sharedpreferences and load onCreate

Comment: @clownba0t I updated my question and added some more info.

Comment: What does the `MainActivity.getInstace()` [sic] method do?

Answer (score 1):

In your onReceive method after getting String value store it in sharedPreference like this

```
public void saveInSharedPreferences(String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("variable",value);//your String value
    editor.commit();
}
```

your onReceive method will be like

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String value =  intent.getExtras().getString("hiddenMessage");
    saveInSharedPreferences(value);
}
```

and in your Activity's onCreate method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     String value = getValueFromSharedPreference();
     if(value != null){
          textview.setText(value);
     }
}
```

getValueFromSharedPreference method

```
public String getValueFromSharedPreference(){
         SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

         return sharedpreferences.getString("variable",null);
}
```

Now if you want to update Textview when your app is open
Try this

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String value =  intent.getExtras().getString("hiddenMessage");
    saveInSharedPreferences(value);
    Intent intent = new Intent("broadcast");
    intent.putExtra("variable",value);
    context.sendBroadCast(intent);
}
```

and then in your Activity's oncreate method

```
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("broadcast"));
```

and then in Your Activity's Class outside oncreate Method

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

          String value = intent.getStringExtra("variable");
          textview.setText(value);
    }
};
```

or you can even use this interface solution:https://stackoverflow.com/a/26268569/6799807

Comment: As I understand, this will update my textView when I open the application. What if my app is already opened?

Comment: Another question is, how can I use method getSharedPreferences in a separate class which only extends BroadcastReceiver? getSharedPreferences is from Context...?

Comment: you can put saveInSharedPreferences method in your class which extends BroadcastReceiver class and then in sharedpreference use context

Comment: One more question is: how can I create a notification from onReceive method so that it will open my application and show message?

Answer (score 0):

First in onRecieve Method save the detail in sql

```
   private void saveNotification(String msg) {
   //notification_sql class to save detail
    Notification_sql n=new Notification_sql(getApplicationContext());
    Notification_detail notification_detail=new Notification_detail();
    //notification detail model class to set and get get detail
    notification_detail.setData(msg);
    n.adddetail(notification_detail);
    }
```

Second save detail in database

```
    public String adddetail(Notification_detail dataval){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DATE_OF_ENTRY,dataval.getData());
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
    return null;
    }
```

Get data using task sheduler in Main Activity

```
    scheduleTaskExecutor= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
    // This schedule a task to run every 10 minutes:
       scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // If you need update UI, simply do this:
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //update text view
                    Notification_sql meter_data=new Notification_sql(MapsActivity.this);
                    //getting detail from database which is saved just after message delivery
                    List<Notification_detail> contacts = meter_data.getDetail();
                    //System.out.println(contacts);
                    for (Notification_detail cn : contacts) {
                        String data=cn.getData();

                       txtdetail.setText(data)
                    }
                }
            });
        }
      }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```