# Pass String data from BroadcastReceiver class to a Android Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an Android application and it has a functionality that while the application is running if user enable or disable GPS. I received the Broadcast and display the status on an activity using Interface.

**GpsLocationReceiver**

```
public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {


        Toast.makeText(context, "GPS Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

I registered this BroadcastReceiver in Manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".GpsLocationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: What is your question? What is problem you are facing?

Comment: i want to pass data from BroadcastReceiver to an activity.

Comment: this will help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137477/passing-data-from-broadcast-receiver-to-another-activity

Comment: @shivpaljodha i want to use Interface not intent.

Answer (score 1):

1. **In Activity**

   ```
    public void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver,  new IntentFilter().addAction("ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE");
       return intentFilter;);
    }

    public void onPause(){
    unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           final String action = intent.getAction();
           if(action.equals("ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE")) {
       }
      }
    };
   ```

   2.**In BroadcastReciver onReciever()**

   ```
   final Intent intent = new Intent("ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE");
   intent.putExtra("KEY","YourString");
   sendBroadcast(intent);
   ```

Comment: can i use Interface for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, you can do by using interface wait i will share you that

Comment: Can you help me to do this using interface?

Comment: Please check the link still  if you have any dought ask me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340934/pass-data-from-broadcastreceiver-class-to-a-android-activity

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

```
  private void sendLocationBroadcast(Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(Data.SHARED_PREF_NAME, 0);
    totaldisplacement = Double.parseDouble(pref.getString(Data.SP_TOTAL_DISTANCE_COVER_TILL, ""));
    intent.putExtra(Data.SP_TOTAL_DISTANCE_COVER_TILL, totaldisplacement);
    intent.putExtra("latitude", currentlat);
    intent.putExtra("longitude", currentlong);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    Log.e("Data", "" + rikshawspeed + " " + currentlat);
}
```

**Step 2**

```
 private void dataSendToMainActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("speedExceeded");
    sendLocationBroadcast(intent);
}
```

**Step 3**

```
   public BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        distanceFromService = intent.getDoubleExtra(Data.SP_TOTAL_DISTANCE_COVER_TILL, 55);
        Double currentLatitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0);
        Double currentLongitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0);
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "speed " + distanceFromService + "\n" + "Lat Long " + "\n" + currentLatitude + "\n" + currentLongitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //  ... react to local broadcast message
        Log.e("Main", "" + distanceFromService);
    }
};
```

**Step 4**

```
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("speedExceeded"));
```