# How to pass data from broadcast receiver to a java class?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I am struck at this point. I need to pass an arraylist from broadcast receiver to a java class in the same application.Could anyone suggest how can I achieve this?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I send result data from Broadcast Receiver to Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661801/how-can-i-send-result-data-from-broadcast-receiver-to-activity)

Comment: I need to send the data to a class. Are both same?